# Input type = "submit" not working in custom-control

Tags: css, angularjs, razor, ng-map

for some reason my input type= "submit" is not working (it's only working for the 1st time). I wrote the input in a custom-control. Will that be a problem?  Help is much appreciated. Thanks. Here is my code.

```js
page.zoom = 4;

page.btn_Click = function() {

  if (page.MobileNo) {
    $http.get(serviceBasePath + '/api/Map/GetDeviceLocation?MobileNo=' + page.MobileNo).then(function(response) {

      var deviceindex = page.DeviceData.findIndex(x => x.DeviceId== response.data.DeviceId);
      if (deviceindex == -1) {
        page.DeviceData.push(response.data);
        page.zoom = 14;
        page.center = response.data.Location.position;
      } else {
        page.zoom = 14;
        page.center = response.data.Location.position;
      }

    }, function(error) {})
  }
}
```

```html
<custom-control style="padding-left:10px; padding-top:10px" position="TOP_LEFT" index="2" on-click="page.btn_Click()">

  <input type="submit" class="form-control" value="GO">

</custom-control>
```

Comment: what is page in js?

Comment: it's a razor page ( .cshtml ) sir.

Comment: why you want to submit you can simply give button?

Comment: The same happening with button too sir. When i press enter or go button, it seems to be working fine ( as it is supposed to), but after the 1st trail, the button becomes irresponsive or rather numb.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing form tag. try this..

HTML::

```
<custom-control style="padding-left:10px; padding-top:10px" position="TOP_LEFT" index="2" on-click="page.btn_Click()">
  <form name="formName" onsubmit="submitForm()">
    <input type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="Enter Your Name">
    <input type="submit" class="form-control" value="GO">
  </form>
</custom-control>
```

Script::

```
function submitForm(){
  //... do something..
};
```

if you want some action on ENTER key then you must have some text fields, else on click it will work.